# Optional start of string with RegEx (PowerShell)

Tags: regex, powershell

How can I optionally allow an SMTP address to start with "smtp:" or "SMTP" and get the below RegEx to match?

```
(?<!-_.)(?!.*\.\.)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9@\-_.]{4,}$)[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{1,64}[a-zA-Z0-9]\@(?:(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,254}\.)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.){1,}[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$
```

I tried different variations of `(smtp:|SMTP:)`, but none seem to work.

Comment: powershell is case _INSENSITIVE_ by default. so you can remove the upper/lower case combos. [*grin*] also, if you want to validate things, try doing it in steps. email and URLs are both notorious for the difficulty in validating them, so i would choose only the simplest - verify the `@` somewhere in the middle and accept anything else since it's likely valid. if you MUST validate an email address to more detail ... try to send it. if it sends, the it's OK.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey the -cmatch operator is used and just leaving it to the imagination is not an option, testing will take some time and is overkill.

Comment: @Emma already used that website, it's handy but doesn't support RegEx in PowerShell format exactly.

Comment: Your question seems to imply the RegEx ***DOES*** match any of the mail addresses (from comments, which should be **in** your question) what is not the case. Start with a simple RE and refine until you get the desired result. In general to make a part optional enclose in parentheses and append a question mark. `((smtp:|SMTP:)(\/\/)?)?`

Comment: @Glenn - ah! well ... NOT including code that you need/want in the question is ... problematic. you really otta _always_ include such info. [*frown*] ///// that aside, as LotPings also pointed out, your doing yourself a disfavor by trying to verify email addresses beyond the minimum needed. if you want to waste your time, that is ok ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey my apologies, I should have been clearer, SMTP validation becomes a thing when you're enforcing naming conventions...

Comment: @Glenn - ah! so it's _internal_ validation. that makes more sense ... thank you for the clarification! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not showing in sample input. Using a made up mail data sample, how about this...

```
$MailData = '
From:smtp:JoeBob@yahoo.com,Tom TheCat tcat@snailmail.net,jerry@snailmail.net 
To:TulaJane@hotmail.com;JF@gmail.com;SMTP:tiger@outlook.com; 
Doug Tompson smtp:DTompson@icloud.com 
MailTo:BobsYourUncle@protonmail.com; 
SMTP:johnny.bravo@yahoo.co.uk
'
[regex]::Matches($MailData,'(smtp[:]|SMTP[:])\w+@\w+\.\w+|(smtp[:]|SMTP[:])\w+\.\w+@\w+\.\w+\.\w+').Value

# Or
[regex]::Matches($MailData,'(smtp.|SMTP.)\w+@\w+\.\w+|(smtp.|SMTP.)\w+\.\w+@\w+\.\w+\.\w+').Value

# Results

smtp:JoeBob@yahoo.com
SMTP:tiger@outlook.com
smtp:DTompson@icloud.com
SMTP:johnny.bravo@yahoo.co.uk
```

Comment: My apologies if I was unclear, I don't want to extract strings. I want to validate a certain SMTP address against the above RegEx and add support should the SMTP start with "smtp:" or "SMTP:".

Comment: gill_bates-gigahard.company@external.gigahard.com = match
smtp:gill_bates-gigahard.company@external.gigahard.com = match
SMTP:gill_bates-gigahard.company@external.gigahard.com = match

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LotPings

((smtp:|SMTP:)(//)?)?(?.)(?!.*..)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9@-.]{4,}$)[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{1,64}[a-zA-Z0-9]@(?:(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,254}.)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*.){1,}[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$